# Redux Store update issue

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an issue updating a object with redux store, when I update it, it removes other parameters.

In the example below, the **id** and **title** parameters are removed when updating **parametersObject**.

```
const initialState = {
    users: {
        'user-0': {
            id: 'user-0',
            title: 'John',
            parametersObject: null
        },
    ....
}

...
ReducerRegistry.register('features/base/users', (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case UPDATE_PARAMETERS_OBJECT:
        return {
            ...state,
            users: {
                ...state.users,
                [action.id]: {
                    ...state.users[action.id],
                    parametersObject: action.parametersObject
                }
            }
        };
    ....
}
```

Am I missing something?
I'm using react 16.9 and redux 4.0.4

Comment: This part of the code seems correct. Can you show a little bit more to the code, specifically how do you pass state to the function that runs the switch statement?

Comment: Maybe too obvious.. but :') What's in `id`? Is it just the ID (`12`) or is it the key you need (`user-12`)? If the former, you need  [`user-${action.id}`]: ... to set the user data in the state.

Comment: -sinan I updated the code
-wrdevos,  it's 'user'12'
I use this state this way to run react-beatiful-dnd

Comment: Do you get the correct user when you try to `console.log(state.users[action.id])` before the return statemeent?

Comment: Yes, and the parametersObject is also correct

Comment: 1). Add console.log or debugger inside `UPDATE_PARAMETERS_OBJECT` block and check what is `action.id` and what does `state.users[action.id]` return. 2). I'd recommend to use redux-toolkit to simplify reducers development

Comment: Also, try to save {
                    ...state.users[action.id],
                    parametersObject: action.parametersObject
                } in separate const and check it

Answer (score 0):

you should check this part [action.id]: {...state.users[action.id]

use console to check what value your are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't know what is wrong with the code. I would try the following as my best attempt:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

case UPDATE_PARAMETERS_OBJECT:
        const tempState = _.cloneDeep(state)
        tempState.users[action.id] = {...tempState.users[action.id], parametersObject: action.parametersObject}
        return tempState
```